# python subprocess stdin.write not writing to subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm currently working on script that can take input from an API, then send the data to a subprocess and receive a response. It’s important that the subprocess keeps running so `subprocess.communicate()` is not an option.

The problem that I’m having is that when I try to write something with `the stdin.write` it won’t write it to the subprocess (like it's never given time to do anything)

The code I used to test it you can see below.

```
def test_os():
    # command_to_execute = ["bricksync-win64/bricksync.exe"]
    command_to_execute = ["cmd", "/c"]
    run = subprocess.Popen(command_to_execute, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                           universal_newlines=True, bufsize=1)

    my_thread = Thread(target=initial_load, args=(run.stdout,))
    my_thread.start()
    time.sleep(2)
    run.stdin.write("dir")
    time.sleep(2)
    run.stdin.write("cd data")
    run.stdin.write("dir")

    return run
```

```
def initial_load(stdout):
    while True:
        line = stdout.readline()
        if line == "":
            break
        print(line)
```

When using this code, the output of `stdout.readline` is empty and nothing is done. but when I add the `dir` command to the `command_to_excecute` it does print the directory where I’m in.

Does anybody know what I’m doing wrong or what I’m missing?

Comment: communicate *is* an option - just give it a timeout and catch the TimeoutExpired exception, then continue with another command. You will also be able to check stdout and stderr between your commands

Comment: @h4z3 I've tryed that but the problem with communicate is that it waits till the subprocess closes. In my case we want to keep the subprocess alive because it needs to do stuff even when it's not given input.

Comment: It waits only if you don't provide the timeout. That's why I said to add timeout and continue on exception instead of killing the process. The docs show an example of killing on exception to show the cleanup, but they are clear that the process still exists